# Euclidean Distance in Model Builder error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, distance, model

I'm trying to use Model Builder to create Euclidean Distance raster files for a set of line features.

Each line also have a buffer polygon that corresponds to each line that I want to have as an extent. However, it doesn't seem to be a way to iterate extents and I get a different looking result file when I use the model in comparison to using only the tool.

How can I run the model so it generates one unique Euclidean raster file for each and everyone of my lines while having the correct buffer as extent? I can do it manually but that would take forever for all of the lines.

Edit:

I made some progress in getting some results. However, I would need some way to iterate the extent each time. If I put in no extent the model crashes and if I use one buffer polygon for extent everything is in the same place, which isn't what I want to achieve.

[image: Model Builder]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your buffer layers have the same name as your line layers then you could use a make feature layer tool using the *Name* output from your iterator to construct a layer, this could then be connected to your euclidean distance tool as an Extent setting.

Comment: Hmm. They don't share a name as of right now since I want several buffers for each line. I don't think it is possible to have them use the same name while covering different areas?

Comment: You could build a full path name with the model only tool Calculate Value.